# Exit(Quit) implementation

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my windows phone7(Silverlight) Application I have to display a message box asking, the user to confirm(Yes/No) before exit from the application [on device back button click].

The problem is I have to use a custom messagebox(using a popup) to get user confirmation, and I have no way to get exit from the application.(No method found which will exit the application like `dispose() or close()`).

if I didn't have to use a custom messagebox, the on the `Device back key press event "OnBackKeyPress"` I would have use the following logic and done my work

```
MessageBoxResult res = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to Exit?", "Exit", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel);

            if (res == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
                {
                    while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
                    {
                        NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
```

The problem is I need to use the custom messagebox and done this work. Same problem arise if need to implement a button to exit the application with out using the device back button.

I found in several posts suggesting to throw an exception and make this done. Following are some of them

http://mobile.dzone.com/articles/windows-phone-mango-sample-3

http://imaginativeuniversal.com/blog/post/2010/08/22/How-to-Quit-a-WP7-Silverlight-Application.aspx

I don't think that this is a good practice and also not sure if the windows market place will certify this way. Would like to hear the thoughts of once who have experienced this issue, and any suggestion to Achieve this(Terminate the application). Thanks inadvance....!!!!

Comment: Not sure why this anonymous down vote......!!!!!

Comment: HI exacerbatedexpert Thanks. Yes I also don't like to exit from the application making an exception. Not a good practice. Do you have any idea of how to implement the "exit" from the application as no method available(Like dispose/close)...

Comment: Hi circumventing. The thing is this is a user requirement. When the user is in the main page and if he press the back button, I have to display a popup message to ask if need to exit or not. If "yes" should exit and if "No" not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to submit to the Marketplace you've got a couple of problems because of the following certification requirements:

> 5.2.4.2 Pressing the Back button from the first screen of an application must close the application.
>
> 5.2.2 A Windows Phone application is closed and terminated by the OS when the user navigates away from the application. When an application is started after being closed, its launch time must meet the requirements in Section 5.2.1 – Launch Time
>
> 5.2.3 A Windows Phone application is deactivated when the user presses the Start button or if the device timeout causes the lock screen to engage. A Windows Phone application is also deactivated with it invokes a Launcher or Chooser API.

This is a couple instances where you simply *can't* display a message box.

And technically using an exception to termniate the app is a violation:

> 5.1.2 The application must handle exceptions raised by the .NET Framework and not close unexpectedly. During the certification process, the application is monitored for unexpected closure. An application that closes unexpectedly fails certification. The application must continue to run and remain responsive to user input after the exception is handled.

As a developer, part of your job is communicating to users about requirements that are unrealistic or unreasonable.

Comment: HI, I am trying to get user confirmation only when user press back button when he is in the first screen. Not in the instances explained under 5.2.2 and 5.2.3. Do you mean when it comes to 5.2.4.2 requirement it can't display a message before execute it(Just to get the confirmation)?

Comment: exacerbatedexpert has explained it very clearly. If you want the app to pass certification, don't try to introduce this dialog and let the Back button and Home button exit the app as expected.

Comment: WP users expect a certain experience. When you alter that experience, and the phone doesn't act the way they expect (pressing back closes the app), your user experience is degraded.  I have seen apps that do exactly what you describe - popping a confirmation on back-press, and I find it to be a pain.  I pressed back BECAUSE I wanted to close the app, and the dev who wrote that app irritates me, and got a not-so-good review, because it does not comply with standards, making for a negative experience.  Now do you see why you should listen to exacerbatedexpert?

Comment: @erbatedexpert: if you want to completely delete the answer for some reason, then delete it using the 'delete' link below the answer. Do *not* deface it by just deleting the text.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, no way to do this. Before mango update you could Clear the back stack, then programmatically trigger the Back button. but as of SDK 7.1 (wp7.5) we can no longer do this.

My recommendation is to create a custom Exception type `ApplicationXExitException` and throw that to exit the app. The reason for the custom type is so that when you pull your exception logs from the marketplace, you'll know the ones that were indeed unintended exceptions *crashing* the app, vs your exception to intentionally exit the app.

Comment: Hi Milan, In a test app project I just added the reference to  "Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game" and when I do "new Game().Exit()" it properly exit from the application. Still wondering which way is the correct. And is market place allowing to add custom exception to exit from the APP?

Comment: please check here http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpdevelop/thread/d66ff941-215a-4bb9-8364-2c2abdd5ea23/, ITs not recommended to use that function. It will not pass the certification process.

Comment: Hi Thanks, Do you mean It will get accepted in the certification process if implement an Exception(Custom) to exit the application?

Comment: I don't know. But from what I have read, some places they say that it will be accepted and you will get the exception as custom exception on the  dev center where as other places they say it might not get accepted. If its worth then you should try submitting with the custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

You can hook an event raising after your custom messagebox closes. Event arguments will keep information about user's choice. Depending on that you will decide whether to exit app or not.

Comment: Hi kvas, Yes I can track the user's choice.... I am looking for a code(way) to exit from the application.